# How to stop false triggering of limit switches by external electrical discharge?

Tags: esd

I have a self built 3D printer type system with some limit switches like the ones shown below. The switches themselves are just glued onto a PLA 3D printed bracket which clamps onto an aluminium frame. I've set up my code so that when the limit switch is hit the axis steps back off the limit switch a certain amount of steps. When I touch the frame with something else that is made of metal the limit switches trigger and the printer axes start moving which I of course don't want. Using a lighter near to the machine or moving a soldering iron near to the machine, and even once lighting outside also triggers the limit switches. My complete circuit diagram is shown below with limit switches at the top. With the STM32 I just have each limit switch connected as an external trigger.

What can I do to stop the false triggering from occuring?

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image: Limit switch]

Comment: Try using a stronger pull-up or pull-down and maybe supplement this with a 10 nF capacitor in series with 100 ohms in parallel with the pu or pd.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, put a pull up or pull down resistor on the output of the microcontroller pin. You can also put a capacitor in series. The reason you're getting false triggering is because when the switch is open, it is floating. This means the pin doesn't have strong signal pulling it high or low. This is why when you touch something on the printer it is false triggering. It's acting similar to how a touch screen works. The small amount of capacitance from the touch changes the state.

In the drawing I have it setup with a pull down. If you have the other side of the switch connected to gnd, you will need a pull up resistor. With signals that leave the board, I typically put a series resistor right on the input of the pin. This makes a small RC filter with the capacitance of input pin and helps reduce any noise that's introduced on that line. Make sure you put the series resistor at the pin and not on the other side of the pull up/ down resistor. This would create a voltage divider and could cause issues.

**EDIT**
Since the Switch is normally closed, a pull down or pull up isn't what is causing the issue that the question is asking. Although they are still needed for when the switch is pressed since the pin will be floating when the switch is pressed.

In the datasheet for the driver on page 3 there is a Block diagram. In your schematic, the enable pin, sense pins, and ROSC pin are not connected. None of these pins should be left floating and should be connected according to the datasheet. You could get a lot of unpredictable events by leaving these pins floating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZgrKG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would add an actual cap, like 0.01uF or so.  The capacitance of the input pin is usually in the pF range.

Comment: The photo of the limit switch shows he's using the normally closed contact. If that's true for all the limit switches, then the symptoms -- false triggering when the limit switches are NOT being pushed -- isn't explained by lack of pullup/pulldown resistors. I'm thinking a ground loop effect, or an intermittent connection. Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2):

I have a different theory. As others have pointed out, adding pullup resistors and debouncing/filter capacitors is still a good idea. But I can't explain your symptoms as a result of that issue, because the photo shows your limit switch is wired using its normally-closed contacts. In this condition -- the input pin of the MCU shorted to ground -- pullups and filtering don't matter.

My theory is you have an intermittent connection between one of the MCU trigger pins and its corresponding limit switch, or between one of the limit switches and ground. Check the voltage at the MCU pins (B0, B1, B15), operate the switches, and jiggle the switches and associated wires. It could also be a cold solder joint affecting the MCU pins. Worth a try.